# How will it be when in glTexImage2D I choose different internal format from how I sample it in shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

For example, I write this in code:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

and in shader:

```
glFragColor = texture2D(sampler, uv).rgba
```

what will happen, is there official definition for this situation?

Comment: The device driver will convert the format to internal format anyway. That is why it is optimal to use the same format as internal, so it doesn't have to convert anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result will be the same, as if you would do the following:

```
glFragColor = vec4( texture2D(sampler, uv).rgb, 1.0 );
```

Because the [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats) specification of Khronos group says:

> Image formats do not have to store each component. When the shader samples such a texture, it will still resolve to a 4-value RGBA vector. The components not stored by the image format are filled in automatically. Zeros are used if R, G, or B is missing, while **a missing Alpha always resolves to 1**.

See further [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 15.2. SHADER EXECUTION; page 487](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)]:

> When a texture lookup is performed in a fragment shader, the GL computes the filtered texture value ... and converts it to a texture base color Cb as shown in table 15.1, ...
>
> ```
> Texture Base Texture base color Internal Format    Cb              Ab
> RED                                                (Rt, 0, 0)      1
> RG                                                 (Rt, Gt, 0)     1
> RGB                                                (Rt, Gt, Bt)    1
> RGBA                                               (Rt, Gt, Bt)    At
> ```
>
> *Table 15.1: Correspondence of filtered texture components to texture base components.*